# How to make GWT Alert prompt large in IE

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I am doing `Window.prompt( <--Large Message-->, "" );` for some operation in Gwt. Now what happening is it is showing correct in Chrome [image: Prompt in Chrome]

but when it comes to Internet Explorer it looks like below where it is cutting the text. [image: Prompt in IE]

I am not checked everywhere but didn't get how to fix this. It will be very helpful if anybody can suggest.

Comment: Perhaps try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162399/gwt-confirmation-dialog-box - http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/GWT/CreateCustomDialog.htm

Comment: Can't I do anything with Window.prompt only. Do I need to create a Dialogbox???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alerts are browser specific and You need to create your own custom Alert box.

See [how to change the style of alert box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853130/how-to-change-the-style-of-alert-box)

Use [PopupPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/PopupPanel.html) or [DecoratedPopupPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DecoratedPopupPanel.html)

[Read more...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167764/is-there-any-way-to-create-something-similar-to-javascripts-alert-in-gwt)

Here is one more [sample](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/GWT/CreateCustomDialog.htm) on Create Custom Dialog or look at [GWT showcase](http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDialogBox)